# If I convert my app to ARC, will it still work on devices running iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I just converted my app to ARC, will the update still work on devices that are running iOS 4?

Also, what about the new UIAlertView Text input styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARC code runs on iOS 4.0+ and Mac OS X 10.6+, however, you can't use the zeroing-weak references. That's only supported on iOS 5+ and Mac OS X 10.7+.

This is documented in [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226).

Comment: Wrong, it is ONLY 4.3 and above. They mention iOS 4 and so mean the latest 4.3 where the OS does not have native ARC support but a static library Apple wrote. This was proved with the WWDC app they wrote

Comment: @LeeArmstrong I'm Sorry, but you're simply wrong. There is no need for any static library to support ARC, just a need for the type of dynamic linking support available in iOS 4.0+. The LLVM compiler emits special ARC code for non-native support. This is why everything but zeroing-weak variables works. This can be trivially shown by running an example app on some non-4.3 version of iOS 4. The only thing you cannot use in Mac OS X 10.6 and iOS 4 is zeroing-weak variables (some support for this actually does exist in 4.3, but it's not really supported).